# Is it possible to tell if a person is awake or sleeping by capturing his finger print at that moment?

Tags: sleep, blood, physiology

Consider A is a person, is there any possibility to find if he is awake or asleep?, Maybe the lines on the finger be compressed or the blood flow might be low while sleeping.

Comment: This is not really related to the question, but consider using **A**lice, **B**ob, **C**harlie etc. instead of A, B, C... to distinguish between hypothetical persons; it makes your sentences easier to read

Answer (score 1):

The fingerprint of a person doesn't change when they're asleep, but their heart rate and breathing slows. It is also possible to determine whether they are asleep or not by monitoring activity in their brain and muscles or watching their eyes. If they are in a REM (rapid eye movement) phase their eyes will move.

Comment: Thank you for your post, however your post does not have references and post on this site require this. Adding these would allow you to follow site guidelines. See the help center for more assistance or ask here. Thank you!